# DNS mapping for GCP DataFlow Kafka to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-networking, google-vpc

Hello i'm trying to run a job to read some events from a kafka hosted outside GCP using dataflow, the job is ran on a VPC network.

Problem is the kafka is configured to answer with hostname instead of IPs, therefore specifying ips in bootstrap results in a failure to connect to the target node when running a job on dataflow.

```
Reader-1: Timeout while initializing partition 'placeholder'. Kafka client may not be able to connect to servers.
```

On the other hand if i create a VM with kafka and specify in `etc/host` the mapping hostname-ip i'm able to consume correctly.
To make it work on Dataflow i tried to create a private Cloud DNS with `DNS name = .` this allows me to create the zone where i can map hosts in each entries `DNS name = nodename1.` to `data = IP1`.

This seems to work as i'm able to `telnet nodename1` on a VM where i didn't specify the mapping in `etc/host`.

However the Job gets stucked in the beginning and the only error i get is:

```
"Timeout in polling result file: gs://placeholder/staging,zone=europe-central2-a/template_launches/2021-09-28_01_43_38-12780367774525067695/operation_result.
Possible causes are:
1. Your launch takes too long time to finish. Please check the logs on stackdriver.
2. Service account placeholder@placeholder may not have enough permissions to pull container image gcr.io/dataflow-templates/2021-09-20-00_rc00/kafka-to-bigquery or create new objects in gs://placeholder.
3. Transient errors occurred, please try again."
```

Is there an easy way to map hosts to ip for a job in dataflow?

Comment: Well this question lacks many details. Did you read official docs - [Using Cloud Dataflow to Process Outside-Hosted Messages from Kafka](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/processing-messages-from-kafka-hosted-outside-gcp) and created two listeners, one `EXTERNAL` with the `Public IP`, and `INTERNAL` with the `Private IP`? Also did you properly configure your firewall?

Comment: Yes i think firewall are not an issue, at least i don't have any problem when trying to consume a message from a VM on compute engine with kafka installed (i only have problems with DataFlow). If there's something else that i might need to configure please let me know. I read the official docs, but i don't understand if that helps me with the mapping host-ip, if so where should i put those informations and furthermore how and where should one edit the config file `server.properties` in a dataflow job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out.

The correct way was not to create a zone with `DNS name=.` , since this would mean that to resolve every domain GCP would look into this zone, not finding anything else other than the `name-ip` entries i created. Since Dataflow workers query 169.254.169.254 internally, this was forwarded to the zone i created and could not be resolved, resulting in the job hanging.

The correct way was to create a zone for each kafka "nodename" with the `DNS name = nodename.` and then map an entry `nodename.-ip`.

By repeating this for every nodename bootstrapped that dataflow was not able to resolve automatically i was able to correctly consume from the kafka topic.

Comment: Great to hear that. Accept your answer. It wont give you reputation points but it will be more visible for others.